# Firebase Storage "ListAll" function result says there are no items

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase Storage to store reviews of songs.

I try to get these reviews by using

```
  let reviews = Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child(self.thedelegate.currentid).child("reviews")
  reviews.listAll { (result, error) in
...
```

but the result says there are no items in the result. I checked for errors - no errors.

It says the count of the result.items array is 0 when I print to the console.

However, in my Firebase Console, the file directory exists, and there are 3 reviews stored in the 'reviews' folder.

I have also made sure that

```
self.thedelegate.currentid
```

is printing out the correct user id.

Here is the function code:

```
 func loadreviews() {

      print("LOADING REVIEWS")
      print("CURRENT ID --- \(self.thedelegate.currentid)")


      let reviews = Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child(self.thedelegate.currentid).child("reviews")
      reviews.listAll { (result, error) in
           if error != nil { return }

           if result.items.count == 0 { print("THERE ARE NO REVIEWS") }  else  { print("THERE ARE REVIEWS") }

           for item in result.items {

                print("CREATING NEW BCELL")

                let newcell = BCell()
                newcell.backgroundColor = .clear
                newcell.selectionStyle = .none
                newcell.intiailize()


                Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child(self.thedelegate.currentid).child("reviews").child(item.name).child("songname").getData(maxSize: 4 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                     if error != nil { return }
                     let songname = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                     newcell.songlabel.text = songname!
                }
                Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child(self.thedelegate.currentid).child("reviews").child(item.name).child("artistname").getData(maxSize: 4 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                     if error != nil { return }
                     let artistname = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                     newcell.artistlabel.text = artistname!
                }
                Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child(self.thedelegate.currentid).child("reviews").child(item.name).child("review").getData(maxSize: 4 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                     if error != nil { return }
                     let review = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                     newcell.reviewlabel.text = review!
                }
                Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child(self.thedelegate.currentid).child("reviews").child(item.name).child("time").getData(maxSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                     if error != nil { return }

                     let stringint = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                     let interval = Int.init(stringint ?? "")
                     newcell.associatedtime = interval!
                     print("THE REVIEW TIME WAS : ")
                     print(interval!)
                }

                newcell.imageview.image = self.thedelegate.correctimage
                self.reviewcells.append(newcell)
                self.table.reloadData()

           }
      }
 }
```

And the pictures of the console and Firebase Storage website

[image: Firebase Storage sheet]

console showing the correct user id

[image: console showing the correct user id]

Comment: The error message is likely correct.  Since we can't see the exact value of `self.thedelegate.currentid`, nor can we see the contents of your storage bucket, there's not much we can do.  Please edit the question to show all the details missing here.  It would be best if you hard code any variables and show a screenshot of your bucket that shows that your path matches the contents of the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows only folders under reviews, and no actual files.  `listAll()` separates files from folders in its API.  Be sure to [read the documentation carefully](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files) on the matter, and study the sample code it provides:

> ```
> let storageReference = storage.reference().child("files/uid")
> storageReference.listAll { (result, error) in
>   if let error = error {
>     // ...
>   }
>   for prefix in result.prefixes {
>     // The prefixes under storageReference.
>     // You may call listAll(completion:) recursively on them.
>   }
>   for item in result.items {
>     // The items under storageReference.
>   }
> }
> ```

If you want to list the folders under a location, you should iterate `result.prefixes`.  To find files immediately under a location, you should iterate `result.items`.  If you want to list nested files, you will have to call listAll() again on the nested path.